# What to do when you find a bug in development?

Tags: team

It is common during development to find bugs in the project, **but when it was not you responsible for that module**, it's correct to add a `FIXME` in the code?
 I see that not put the annotation that can be taken to production and bring future problems.

Comment: Well, if you don't have a bug-tracking system you can just enter this in to, do you have anyone who keeps track of who's doing what to the code? If so, talk to them - just a comment in the code may mean nobody finds it, whereas if you tell someone, it may actually get fixed.

Comment: Hello Daniela and welcome to the Workplace. I'm afraid this is completely off-topic; the only way to save it is to edit as "what should I do if I find a mistake in a project I'm not responsible for", which is overly broad in itself. I hope this helps. _To answer your question: ask your manager!_

Comment: Is there any way to transfer this question for programmers.se?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for Programmers Stack Exchange. I'd look for related duplicates, but this reads very much like a poll, asking developers what they or their organization does. The correct answer is, simply, to follow your team's process. The community doesn't know your team's process, so we can't tell you the right thing to do in your team or company. Ask someone on your team.

Comment: I voted to close because this should be covered by the development team policies and only the dev manager can answer the question for your environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really a workplace question, probably more for programmers.se but as a development manager my answer would be this:

A development team should exercise shared ownership, so if you find a bug, add it to your bug tracker, talk to your lead/dev manager about whether it is higher priority than what you are doing/going to do next, and if so fix it.  If it's not important enough to fix now (and in production systems this can be the case), it'll get reviewed at the planning for the next iteration of work.

Leaving a FIXME is just ignoring the issue, it'll be forgotten about and never fixed. My team had to pick up a code base with TODOs in the code, gave up on planning to fix them when the find/replace found 70000 (the code base had been worked on by a team of 200 for 5+ years) some of which had been in production for years (so would probably break workarounds by fixing now), we ended up doing a replace to remove them on the basis that all the risks were acceptable in production due to age.

Answer (score 4):

Log it as a ticket in your management system. The project manager can then assign it to the correct person to fix, or it will go into a backlog for a look later.

Your responsibility is just to log it so others know of it. Do you have a bug reporting system?

However, if the fix is simple, and you're actually in the relevant file, then it maybe just quicker for you to fix it.